# How to plot accuracy, precision and recall in confusion matrix plot using seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I want to plot precision, and recall and accuracy of my prediction in confusion matrix using `seaborn`. The figure i want to achieve is.

This image:

[image: This image].

So I tried to fit my model with data, and got the following confusion matrix.

Image_confusion matrix:

[image: Image_confusion matrix].

Confusion Matrix:

```
col_0          0   1   2   3
Damage state                
0             65   0   0   0
1              0  51   0   0
2              0   0  31   1
3              0   0   0  52
```

I print the classification report and got these values.

```
    precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00        65
           1       1.00      1.00      1.00        51
           2       1.00      0.97      0.98        32
           3       0.98      1.00      0.99        52

    accuracy                           0.99       200
   macro avg       1.00      0.99      0.99       200
weighted avg       1.00      0.99      0.99       200
```

```
print(classification_report(Y_train, y_train_pred))
```

Then i plotted my confusion matrix using seaborn.

```
#Import confusion matrix library
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

c_mat = confusion_matrix(Y_train, y_train_pred)
group_counts = ["{0:0.0f}".format(value) for value in
                c_mat.flatten()]
group_percentages = ["{0:.2%}".format(value) for value in
                     c_mat.flatten() / np.sum(c_mat)]
labels = [f"{v1}\n{v2}" for v1, v2 in
          zip(group_counts,group_percentages)]
labels = np.asarray(labels).reshape(4,4)
disp = sns.heatmap(c_mat, annot=labels, cmap='Reds', fmt='', xticklabels=["D1","D2","D3","D4"]
                   , yticklabels=["D1","D2","D3", "D4"], cbar=False)
disp.plot()
plt.title('Predicted Damage State', fontweight='bold')
plt.tick_params(labeltop=True, labelbottom=False)
plt.ylabel('Actual Damage State', fontweight='bold')
plt.show()
```

And i achieved this:

[image: Confusion matrix achieved]

Is there any way i can achieve the desired figure as shown above.

Comment: What do you consider missing? The formatting? The headings? Or just the extra column and row?

Comment: The extra column and row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw a second heatmap onto the same subplot (`ax`). That heatmap starts from a matrix that has one row and one column more than the given confusion matrix. The part that overlaps with to the confusion matrix can be masked away.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib. Colors import ListedColormap
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

c_mat = np.array([[65, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 51, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 31, 1],
                  [0, 0, 0, 52]])
total = np.sum(c_mat)
labels = [[f"{val:0.0f}\n{val / total:.2%}" for val in row] for row in c_mat]
states = ["D1", "D2", "D3", "D4"]

ax = sns.heatmap(c_mat, annot=labels, cmap='Reds', fmt='',
                 xticklabels=states, yticklabels=states, cbar=False)
ax.set_title('Predicted Damage State', fontweight='bold')
ax.tick_params(labeltop=True, labelbottom=False, length=0)
ax.set_ylabel('Actual Damage State', fontweight='bold')

# matrix for the extra column and row
f_mat = np.zeros((c_mat.shape[0] + 1, c_mat.shape[1] + 1))
f_mat[:-1, -1] = np.diag(c_mat) / np.sum(c_mat, axis=1)  # fill recall column
f_mat[-1, :-1] = np.diag(c_mat) / np.sum(c_mat, axis=0)  # fill precision row
f_mat[-1, -1] = np.trace(c_mat) / np.sum(c_mat)  # accuracy

f_mask = np.ones_like(f_mat)  # puts 1 for masked elements
f_mask[:, -1] = 0  # last column will be unmasked
f_mask[-1, :] = 0  # last row will be unmasked

# matrix for coloring the heatmap
# only last row and column will be used due to masking
f_color = np.ones_like(f_mat)
f_color[-1, -1] = 0  # lower right gets different color

# matrix of annotations, only last row and column will be used
f_annot = [[f"{val:0.2%}" for val in row] for row in f_mat]
f_annot[-1][-1] = "Acc.:\n" + f_annot[-1][-1]

sns.heatmap(f_color, mask=f_mask, annot=f_annot, fmt='',
            xticklabels=names + ["Recall"],
            yticklabels=names + ["Precision"],
            cmap=ListedColormap(['skyblue', 'lightgrey']), cbar=False, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn confusion matrix with extra column for recall and row for precision]